# Guardar un dato en el RecyclerView

Tags: android, studio

Actualizo el problema, lo he pasado todo a fragments, ya que tenia que poder eliminar un dato... Alguien sabría decirme porque no me funciona el botón de escanear? No se me ejecuta y no encuentro el fallo, dejo el código por si alguien consigue ver que falla.

No he conseguido averiguar en que momento me ha dejado de fallar, ya que lo habia estado probando y iba bien, el codigo leido se mostraba por pantalla y se habria la camara correctamente.

Cuando he intentado probar de nuevo, ya no me funcionaba el botón..

```
public class EscanerFragment extends Fragment {

EditText etCodigo;
Button btnEscanearCodigo;


public EscanerFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escaner, container, false);

    etCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.etCodigo);
    btnEscanearCodigo = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_escanear);

    btnEscanearCodigo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            escanear();
        }
    });

    return vista;
}

public void escanear(){
    IntentIntegrator intent = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(EscanerFragment.this);
    intent.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    intent.setPrompt("ESCANEAR CODIGO");
    intent.setCameraId(0);
    intent.setBeepEnabled(true);
    intent.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
    intent.initiateScan();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents() == null){
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Has salido del escaneo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            etCodigo.setText(result.getContents().toString());
        }
    }else{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Dale a [edit] para agregar lo que has intentado y así sea más fácil ayudarte. Revisa el apartado [ask] para crear una publicación que sea de mayor interés y así encontrar una respuesta a tu pregunta. También puedes hacer el [tour] y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a guardar la cadena que recibes en `onActivityResult`? Porque en el recycler tienes un adapter con un array de objetos de una clase `Producto`, no un array de cadenas. En general te diré que tienes que pasarle los datos a mostrar en el adapter (para lo que tendrás que implementar una función en el adapter para recibir esos datos y actualizar su lista interna. Y luego llamar a `notifyDataSetChanged` del adapter para que repinte.

Comment: Exacto, esa cadena guardarla y mostrarla en el recyclerview, entonces me creo un array de cadenas, tanto en el mainActivity como en el adaptador no? Y en el adaptador en el onBindViewHolder.. le paso el array... Perdona por explicarme tan mal

Comment: te fijaste que la lista que estas poniendo en el recycler no sea vacia ?

Comment: @gastonsaillen Claro, lo que quiero es que este vacía al principio y que después según vaya escaneando, se vaya rellenando

Comment: El recyclerView se me muestra bien, lo he rellenado a mano y funciona, pero sigo sin conseguir guardar la cadena que recibo en el onActivityResult